Tabs not swiping or clickable when using dynamic parsedResponse in React Native Material Top Tab Navigator
I'm working with React Native and using createMaterialTopTabNavigator to create a tab navigator. The tabs work fine when I hardcode the parsedResponse data, but they don't swipe or respond to clicks when parsedResponse is passed as a parameter to the component.
packages used:
npm install @react-navigation/material-top-tabs react-native-tab-view react-native-pager-view.
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const Category2_Grid_List_view = ({ parsedResponse = [], selectedBranches = [] }) => {
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

  const subPages = Array.isArray(parsedResponse) && parsedResponse[0]?.SubPageDetails
    ? parsedResponse[0].SubPageDetails.filter((item) => item.ShowSubPage).sort((a, b) => a.SubPageOrder - b.SubPageOrder)
    : [];

  const Payments = () => <View style={ styles.screen }> <Text>Payments Screen < /Text></View >;
  const PaymentsHistory = () => <View style={ styles.screen }> <Text>Payments History Screen < /Text></View >;

  return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator= { false} 
    style = {{ marginBottom: '100%' }>
    <View style={ { flex: 1 } }>
     { subPages.length > 0 ? (
      <View style= {{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={ styles.subArrowButton }>
          <Ionicons name="chevron-back-sharp" size = { 30} color = "#00a4e0" />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            < Tab.Navigator
                initialRouteName = { subPages[0]?.SubPageName } 
                screenOptions = {{
                tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
                tabBarActiveTintColor: '#00a4e0',
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#666666',
                tabBarLabelStyle: {
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                textAlign: 'center',
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                flexShrink: 0,
                overflow: 'visible',
                },
                tabBarStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                },
                tabBarIndicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: '#00a4e0' },
                }}
            >
                { subPages.map((subPage) => (
                    <Tab.Screen
                    key= { subPage.SubPageId }
                    name = { subPage.SubPageName }
                    component = { subPage.SubPageName === "Teaching Staff" ? Payments : PaymentsHistory }
                    options = {{
                    tabBarLabel: ({ color }) => (
                        <View style= { styles.subTabsContainer } >
                            <Text 
                                style={{
                                color,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                textAlign: 'center',
                                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                                overflow: 'visible',
                                flexShrink: 0,
                                }}
                                > { subPage.SubPageName } </Text>
                        </View>
                    ),
                    }}
                    />
                    ))}
                    </Tab.Navigator>

                    < TouchableOpacity style = { styles.subArrowButton } >
                        <Ionicons name="chevron-forward-sharp" size = { 30} color = "#00a4e0" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                        ) : (
                            <View style= { styles.noTabsContainer } >
                            <Text style={ styles.noTabsText }> No subpages available </Text>
                                </View>
                            )}
                            </View>
    </ScrollView>
        );
        };

export default Category2_Grid_List_view;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  subArrowButton: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  subTabsContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  noTabsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  noTabsText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#666666',
  },
});


It is hard to tell what is the source of problem because I can't see how parsedData is got. Can it be that your http response contains some additional field like data? As a result your parsedData param is empty array.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

After facing this issue where the tabs wouldn't swipe or respond to clicks when parsedResponse was passed as a parameter, I implemented a temporary workaround. Instead of using createMaterialTopTabNavigator, I used a FlatList to replicate the tab UI look and feel.
While this approach doesn't provide the swiping functionality, it allowed me to achieve the desired look.
